# How can I edit the CNAME and TXT records on Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, dns

I'm migrating a website to a new Ubuntu 18.04 server.

I'd like to create TXT and CNAME records, but I can't find any tutorials on the subject.

Is it possible to create these records in something like Putty?

Or is there another way I should be going about this?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/what-are-cname-and-a-dns-records suggests the CNAME record lives in your nameserver. and https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35662/where-do-i-set-my-spf-record-for-domain-managed-by-yahoo suggests the TX record is also there. Where is your nameserver?

Comment: This helps explain why I couldn't find any tutorials for Ubuntu. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in Ubuntu or in any OS on a web server. It's in your nameserver.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/what-are-cname-and-a-dns-records shows the CNAME record lives in your nameserver. and https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35662/where-do-i-set-my-spf-record-for-domain-managed-by-yahoo states the TX record is also there.